Why am I getting a build failure for this Maven build?
I keep getting this message while trying to run a maven dependency check in the Eclipse IDE.BUILD FAILURE "ERROR The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory" The code base was all given to us, all we had to add was the code for the maven dependency check plug in.  I have not altered any of the code that was provided to us.  I emailed my professor but have not received any response.  This assignment was due last Sunday, and I have a project due this Sunday that needs to run the same dependency check. Please help.
Project Code
Remaining code
The maven dependency check was supposed to generate an html report for me to analyze for security vulnerabilities.  All I got was a build failure.  Not sure why I always have such a hard time with Maven in my classes.

The error: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory" tells you that the pom file is not in the root location of your project...

Like I said, I didn't alter any of the code given to us. We were only supposed to add the code to the pom.xml to make it run the dependency check and create the html file in the target directory. I don't even see any pom file anywhere in the files of the project.

@ennifer Lozier  , You executed the mvn command in the wrong directory (there is no pom.xml in it). Please confirm whether there is a pom.xml file in the directory where you executed the mvn command?

Yes, I added the code to the pom.xml file as we were instructed to do.  The code that I posted is the pom.xml file. That's one reason why I'm so confused.
